# Retrieve my previous arrival and departure dates at Hong Kong

Tags: hong-kong

I want to know how I can get my previous arrival and departures record at Hong Kong.

Answer (score 4):

The [Government of Hong Kong has a process](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/forms/forms/id697.html) through which you can request Immigration Department records.

> [Application for a Statement of Travel Records](https://www.immd.gov.hk/pdforms/id697.pdf)
>
> This form is for persons who wish to apply for a “Statement of Travel Records” in Hong Kong. Please read the “Notes for guidance” in the application form before completing the form.
>
> E-mail address for enquiries: enquiry@immd.gov.hk
>
> Submission of Completed Forms Mailing Address:  
>   Records Centre, Immigration Department
>   12/F, Immigration Tower, 7 Gloucester Road, Wan Chai, Hong Kong
>
> Completed form (ID 697) should be submitted together with completed Acknowledgement Card (ID 697A) and Mailing Label (ID 839)
>
> Underpaid mail items will not be accepted by the Immigration Department. For proper delivery of your mail items, please ensure your mail items bear sufficient postage with return address before posting. ([Details](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/pay_sufficient_postage.html))
>
> In Person To:   
>   Receipt and Despatch Sub-unit, Immigration Department
>   2/F, Immigration Tower, 7 Gloucester Road, Wan Chai, Hong Kong
>
> Fax To: Not Accepted
>
> Telephone Enquiry Number:   (852) 2824 6111