# Does some US agency keep track of one's domestic (= within the US) travels by plane, and if so, can one get a copy of it?

Tags: usa, air-travel

Some countries record passenger travels and allow passengers to see these records, e.g. one can [retrieve one's previous arrival and departure dates at Hong Kong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/124277/1810).

Does some US agency keep track of one's domestic (= within the US) travels by plane, and if so, can one get a copy of it?

Comment: It's not what you asked, but the CBP does get PNR data for _international_ travel to or from the US, and [you can request a copy of this data if you want](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2020-May/PNR-FAQs-%28508-compliant%29.pdf).

Comment: How much effort are you willing to put into getting a copy of the data (if any exists)? Is something like filing a [FOIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States)) request good enough for you?

Comment: Are you trying to get your own or someone else's?

Comment: @whatsisname mine

Comment: @TooTea I'm ok to file a FOIA if needs be.

Comment: I'm sure the NSA does, but good luck getting anything out of them.

Comment: The TSA [keeps records of passengers on flights](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2012/11/19/2012-28058/privacy-act-of-1974-system-of-records-secure-flight-records) so it should be possible to make a FOIA request to DHS for your own records. That said, I've not done this (nor have I heard of anyone else doing it) and have no idea how long they keep them for.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all airlines use a GDS system and if you happen to live in California then under the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA) you have the [right to know](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa#sectionc) what data they store about you from the last twelve months. Three GDSes that matter are Amadeus, Sabre and Travelport (which includes Apollo, Galileo and Worldspan but since we will be dealing with companies this doesn't matter). I know this is not what you asked but this is AFAIK the best you can do currently.